# 'argument' : ambiguous conversions from 'Foo *const ' to 'IUnknown *'

Tags: com, atl

I've got an ATL class:

```
class Foo :
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComMultiThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<Foo, &CLSID_Foo>,
    public IPlugin,
    public IEventSubscriber
{
    // ...
};
```

I need to pass it to another object, like this:

```
pOther->MethodTakingIUnknown(this);
```

When I do this, I get the following error message:

```
error C2594: 'argument' : ambiguous conversions from 'Foo *const' to 'IUnknown *'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both `IPlugin` and `IEventSubscriber` are derived from `IUnknown` and so C++ can't decide on its own which one of `IUnknown`s to cast to implicitly. You need to explicitly tell C++ which one you want. There're two options: either call `GetUnknown()` (is available in every class having a COM map declared):

```
pOther->MethodTakingIUnknown(GetUnknown());
```

or explicitly cast `this` to one of the base interfaces:

```
pOther->MethodTakingIUnknown( static_cast<IPlugin*>( this ) );
```

In this very case it doesn't matter which base interface you cast to - just cast to any. It only matters when you implement `IUnknown::QueryInterface()` to consistently cast to the very same base every time.

Comment: +1: Better answer than mine, because it covers the non-ATL case as well.